# Sell physical product in an iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I wonder what rules there are to sell physical products in an iOS app? The payment is not going to be using apples in-app purchase.

Comment: I wonder how that is a programming related question.

Comment: Didn't know where to ask... And it can be a kind of API question. Perhaps there are rules how to program it... I don't know. But if you have better suggestion where I can put this question, tell me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are simple:

- Any digital stuff that could be used by your app must be paid using in-app billing
- Any physical stuff shouldn't be sold through In-App purchases, it should use something else, the [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/) for example

Comment: Ok, that's sound simple. Apple take revenue using the in-app billing, do they do that with physical stuff as well?

Comment: Nope they dont, they not even know that you sold something